# get-eventlog issue

Tags: powershell

I wanted to get a quick report of some log entries I saw on a server, so I ran:

```
Get-Eventlog -logname system -newest 10 -computer fs1 | fl
```

I got events back however the descriptions were all wrong. Here's an example:

> Index : 1260055 EntryType : Warning InstanceId : 2186936367
>   Message : The description for Event ID
>   '-2108030929' in Source 'W32Time'
>   cannot be found. The local compute r
>   may not have the necessary registry
>   information or message DLL files to
>   display the message, or you may not
>   have permission to access them. The
>   following information is part of the
>   event:'time. windows.com,0x1' Category
>   : (0) CategoryNumber : 0
>   ReplacementStrings :
>   {time.windows.com,0x1} Source :
>   W32Time TimeGenerated : 1/25/2010
>   10:43:31 AM TimeWritten : 1/25/2010
>   10:43:31 AM UserName :

Note that if I pull the event ID property it's correct (in this case 38)

Is this is known issue or is something wrong.  The messages resolve fine via event viewer locally and remotely

Here is the powershell version info:

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : bc58fcf8-bba3-4ca8-8972-17dbd5d9ff08
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Here is the revised version info:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3603
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue in beta versions of PowerShell. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Jim B: You can find out your PowerShell version via `$host.Version` - I would also like to know what version you are using, Jim B.

Comment: The right way to check PowerShell version is to use $psversiontable variable. I would like to suggest to look at http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/21/are-you-using-the-correct-powershell-version.aspx and use Test-PSVersion function. You can run it against remote computer as well.